# How to create sheet for csv

Tags: flutter, csv, export-to-csv, flutter-dependencies

I have something like this:

```
List<dynamic> associateList = [
      {
        "taxes": "100",
      },
    ];

    List<List<dynamic>> rows = [];

    List<dynamic> row = [];
    row.add("Taxes");
    rows.add(row);
    for (int i = 0; i < associateList.length; i++) {
      List<dynamic> row = [];
      row.add(associateList[i]["taxes"]);
      rows.add(row);
    }
    String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
```

This file is generated fine but how can I generate another sheet for the same file?

Comment: What do you mean with _"another sheet for the same file"_. It's a CSV (which is just a plain text file!), not an Excel file.

Comment: My mistake then. The app I have on the phone opens it like a normal excel file

Comment: That just means your phone has a default association to Excel (or an Excel-like application), and parses and imports the data from the CSV.